# Custom Roles for BigQuery Datasets

Tags: security, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to (programmatically or via UI) assign custom roles to BigQuery Datasets? We would like to have access controls at a more granular level within a project, but I cannot find any indication that these are supported, or that they are not supported. The "share dataset" UI n BigQuery does not offer an obvious way to specify which roles have access.

This is the best I could do so far, but it throws an error about the entity_id

```
for dataset in datasets:
    dataset_ref = bigquery.Dataset(dataset, frankie_client)
    entry = bigquery.AccessGrant(
        role='projects/xxxxxx/roles/custom_role1',
        entity_type='specialGroup',
        entity_id='projects/xxxxxx/roles/custom_role1')
    assert entry not in dataset_ref.access_grants
    entries = list(dataset_ref.access_grants)
    entries.append(entry)
    dataset_ref.access_grants = entries

    dataset = dataset_ref.update()  # API request

    assert entry in dataset.access_entries
```

By the way, google's API is incredibly unstable and poorly documented.... If anyone knows how to do this, would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can add custom roles to datasets via gcloud or API. See here for details (check the CLI tab in the code example section) https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATE AT THE END**.

There is a long documentation page describing all the roles and discusses custom roles as well.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control

I think what you missed is that you need to apply a group on a dataset. And if you setup the group correctly you can do a lot of flexible things.

Check out the examples scenarios section in the linked page. That has your use case explained.

**Read and write access to data in a dataset**

`CompanyProject` is a project that includes `dataset1` and `dataset2`. `AnalystGroup1` is a group of data scientists who work only on `dataset1` and `AnalystGroup2` is a group that works only on `dataset2`. The data scientists should have access only to the dataset that they work on and should not be able to run queries.

**Full access to a dataset**

- On dataset `CompanyProject:dataset1`  Add `AnalystGroup1` to the predefined role `bigquery.dataOwner`.
- On dataset `CompanyProject:dataset2`  Add `AnalystGroup2` to the predefined role `bigquery.dataOwner`.

In addition to the pre-defined roles, BigQuery also supports **custom roles**. For more information, see [Creating and Managing Custom Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) in the Cloud IAM documentation.

To add more, in the [IAM page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project), you are able to see much easier the roles an assigned user has. And the custom role you created is grouped under the Custom label.

[image]

**Update**

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#custom_roles) has been improved after my [issue ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70755137).

> Note: Currently, you cannot apply a custom role to a dataset. For more
>   information on dataset access controls, see [Assigning access controls](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#dataset-acl)
>   to datasets.

Comment: I think the question was specifically about Custom Roles in BigQuery (not about pre-defined ones). Can you elaborate on `Custom Roles` here?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  While I appreciate the answer here, I am asking specifically about how to apply custom roles at the dataset level, which is not described anywhere in the documentation.   The link you provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#custom_roles) is woefully inadequate (google's fault not yours) to describe how these should be applied in bigquery, or whether this is even possible yet.   I have had no trouble creating the roles.

Comment: Thank you @Pentium10 - now it makes sense. Honestly, I was confused by myself as was not able to find how to make it work so thought I might be missing something